# Scroll two WPF(!) Richtextboxes synchronously without WPF Scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I've a little problem but I can't find a solution. The solutions I've found are only working for Richtextbox in Winforms, but not in WPF.

What I'd like to do:
I have a WPF View with two RichtextBoxes side by side. When I scroll vertically by using the integrated scroll the second richtextbox should scroll vertically also.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this using a the scrollbar you can do this. However this does not appear to work when using the mouse scroll wheel.

One of the textboxes in the XAML.

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="richText1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollBar.Scroll="richText1_Scroll" />
```

and the code behind.

```
private void richText1_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    richText2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
}
```

You may wish to repeat this for the other text box too.

Comment: I'm such a fool, sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees!